# update all files

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `models.manager` where I can filter files from:

```
class FileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_new_files(self, json_output=None, update=None):
        files = (self.filter(status=File.PENDING_STATUS)) \
                     .values('name', 'link', 'size', 'token__userid', 'token__credentials')
```

How do I update all files in the very same function (change the status to `PROGRESS`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update the `status` field:

```py
class FileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_new_files(self, json_output=None, update=None):
        files = (self.filter(status=File.PENDING_STATUS)) \
                 .values('name', 'link', 'size', 'token__userid', 'token__credentials')

        self.filter(status=File.PENDING_STATUS).update(status=File.PROGRESS)
```

See the docs on [`QuerySet.update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) method. Note that **you can't chain [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) and [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) methods in the same call**.